# PostgreSQL, Custom aggregate

Tags: postgresql

Is here way to get function like custom aggregate when MAX and SUM is not enough to get result?
Here is my table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
CREATE TABLE temp1(mydate text, code int, price decimal);
INSERT INTO temp1 (mydate, code, price) VALUES 
('01.01.2014 14:32:11', 1,   9.75), 
(                   '', 1,   9.99), 
(                   '', 2,  40.13), 
('01.01.2014 09:12:04', 2,  40.59), 
(                   '', 3,  18.10), 
('01.01.2014 04:13:59', 3,  18.20), 
(                   '', 4,  10.59), 
('01.01.2014 15:44:32', 4,  10.48), 
(                   '', 5,   8.19), 
(                   '', 5,   8.24), 
(                   '', 6,  11.11), 
('04.01.2014 10:22:35', 6,  11.09), 
('01.01.2014 11:48:15', 6,  11.07), 
('01.01.2014 22:18:33', 7,  22.58), 
('03.01.2014 13:15:40', 7,  21.99), 
(                   '', 7,  22.60);
```

Here is query for getting result:

```
SELECT code, 
       ROUND(AVG(price), 2), 
       MAX(price) 
  FROM temp1 
 GROUP BY code 
 ORDER BY code;
```

In short: 
I have to get LAST price by date (written as text) for every grouped code if date exists otherwise (if date isn't written) price should be 0.
In column LAST is wanted result and result of AVG and MAX for illustration:

```
  CODE    LAST     AVG     MAX  
 ------------------------------
     1    9.75    9.87    9.99
     2   40.59   40.36   40.59
     3   18.20   18.15   18.20
     4   10.48   10.54   10.59
     5    0.00    8.22    8.24
     6   11.09   11.09   11.11
     7   21.99   22.39   22.60
```

How would I get wanted result?
How that query would look like?

**EDITED**
I simply have to try 'IMSoP's advices to update and use custom aggregate functions first/last.

```
    SELECT code, 
       CASE WHEN MAX(mydate)<>'' THEN
           (SELECT last(price ORDER BY TO_TIMESTAMP(mydate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')))
            ELSE
            0
            END AS "LAST",
       ROUND(AVG(price), 2) AS "AVG", 
       MAX(price) AS "MAX"
  FROM temp1 
 GROUP BY code 
 ORDER BY code;
```

With this simple query I get same results as with Mike's complex query.
And more, those one better consumes double (same) entries in mydate column, and is faster.
Is this possible? It look's similar to 'SELECT * FROM magic()' :)

Comment: Did you check out the `last_value()` function? Btw: never, ever store dates as `varchar`. That is begging for trouble.

Comment: OK, those dates now is 'as is' and I can't do much there but I can apply that for a future. Can datetime column be empty? I see now for last_value but I don't know to apply it in concrete situation. Can you provide short example with query based on my 'easy-to-use' data?

Comment: @user973238 Any column can be set to `null` (if you do not set a `NOT NULL` constraint).

Comment: As an alternative to window functions, you could try these [`first()` and `last()` aggregate functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_%28aggregate%29), e.g. `SELECT last(price ORDER BY date)`

Comment: Well, that look's nice but is too complicated for me :) Can those functions be maded with pure SQL from program?

Comment: Can one code have two rows with the same date?

Comment: Yes it can have. In that case may be used MAX function for those entries.

Comment: @user973238 Why did you title your question "custom aggregate", if copy and pasting a custom aggregate definition is too complicated? Once you've created them, that's a lot simpler than any other approach I can conceive of.

Comment: Because I thought on solution based on SQL from my program and not by usage of script language.

Comment: @user973238 There isn't really a "script language" there, the language is SQL. All those definitions do is create `first()` and `last()` aggregates that work the same way as `min()` and `max()`. That's what "custom aggregate" means - an aggregate which is not built into the database, so you create it yourself. You don't need to understand how `CREATE AGGREGATE` works to use them, just run it once like you would `CREATE TABLE`, and you're done.

Comment: @user973238 Complicated requirements, complicated answer. Sometimes things just can't be reduced to "SELECT * FROM magic()"

Comment: Yes, I didn't though at all that this is such kind of problem and I was hoping that in last case I can solve this by myself. But now I see I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said in comments that one code can have two rows with the same date.  So this is sane data.

```
01.01.2014  1   3.50
01.01.2014  1  17.25
01.01.2014  1  99.34
```

There's no deterministic way to tell which of those rows is the "last" one, even if you sort by code and "date". (In the relational model--a model based on mathematical sets--the order of columns is irrelevant, and the order of rows is irrelevant.) The query optimizer is free to return rows is the way it thinks best, so this query

```
select *
from temp1
order by mydate, code
```

might return this on one run,

```
01.01.2014  1   3.50
01.01.2014  1  17.25
01.01.2014  1  99.34
```

and this on another.

```
01.01.2014  1   3.50
01.01.2014  1  99.34
01.01.2014  1  17.25
```

Unless you store some value that makes the meaning of *last* obvious, what you're trying to do isn't possible. When people need to make *last* obvious, they usually use a timestamp.

---

After your changes, this query seems to return what you're looking for.

```
with distinct_codes as (
  select distinct code 
  from temp1
),
corrected_table as (
select 
  case when mydate <> '' then TO_TIMESTAMP(mydate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       else null
  end as mydate, 
  code, 
  price
from temp1
),
max_dates as (
  select code, max(mydate) max_date
  from corrected_table
  group by code
)
select c1.mydate, d1.code, coalesce(c1.price, 0)
from corrected_table c1
inner join max_dates m1
        on m1.code = c1.code
       and m1.max_date = c1.mydate
right join distinct_codes d1
        on d1.code = c1.code
order by code;
```

Comment: I understand now, but OK, I changed data to datetime now since I can get real time with real data. Since and date and time is written like text we could use function TO_TIMESTAMP(mydate || mytime, 'DD.MM.YYYYHH24:MI:SS'). How would then query look like?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood me. I was suggesting you either change your existing "mydate" column to type timestamp, or add an additional column of type timestamp. Timestamp; not text or char(n) or varchar(n).

Comment: I gave example most similar to concrete situation, easy-to-use table and best description of problem I know. Everything above would be some other situation than one which I asked to help solving.

Comment: Well, I wasn't aware that this is so complex problem which require that complex query. It work as expected on my data, thank you for solving a problem.

Comment: If you have a table of codes, you could rewrite this without the first common table expression (CTE). If you had sensible data types, you could eliminate the second CTE. What's left after those two changes is pretty straightforward.

Comment: OK, thanks Mike. I will for sure back to this routine with my SQL advancing. As for now I incorporated this into my existed process (with few unioned and few temporary tables :) and it work well. And yes, I have some datetimes which may be a same so with first chance I will replace those text columns with timestamps with milliseconds to get unique values in mydate column. For now I am satisfied how this works. In case when accidentally values in mydate+code is a same with different price then 'choosen' price may not be expected one but for my purposes that rare case is 'acceptable fault'.